# Can't access [myself] of myself in nested ask

Tags: nested, netlogo

I want to calculate the mean of the weight of some of the links, called "fs", of a turtle (let's call it turtle A). 
In particular, I need to select the turtles that have a "C" breed of link with another turtle, B, and calculate the mean of the weights of fs links of turtle A with this agentset.
I am doing it with a reporter, mean-fs.
 To select the links I want to calculate the mean of, I need to nest some ask and access [myself] of myself, which should be turtle A.

I've tried passing who of turtle A to the reporter mean-fs, but there is the error "expected literal value".
I've tried with [myself] of myself but it returns self.
Here is the part of the code I'm talking about:

```
to go
ask turtles
[move
set-conv]
end

to set-conv
  ask other turtles in-cone 4 120
  [...
   if (C-neighbors != nobody)[add-partecipant]
  ]
end

to add-partecipant
  let turtle1 myself
  if ( mean-fs [ turtle1 ] > 0 )
  [ ... ]
end

to-report mean-fs [turtle1]
  let w-list []
  ask C-neighbors
  [ set w-list lput [w] of f-with turtle1 w-list]
  report mean w-list
end
```

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?